# Captions gets extra line between object

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, caption

My problem is pretty annoying

I am adding caption to my table, image etc any object

And these captions sometimes gets extra new line

I mean an empty line between caption and the object

When i delete this new line the caption becomes regular text and reference disappears

How can i solve this extremely annoying problem?

It is word 2013

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or better yet upload the document with the issue. Your description here is not sufficient to give an answer especially when you say `sometimes gets extra new line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by relatively minimizing the object width

when you let it automatically assign its width this problem can happen